# Where is USB -stick automounted in OSX? Not /media/usb/something like in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, console

Ubuntu automounts USB -fs to `/media/usb/something`. How is this in OSX? I cannot find anything in /media below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All volumes (CDs, USB, harddrives, etc) are mounted into /Volumes.

After inserting a USB stick called **USB** I see the following:

```
alex@smiley:/Volumes|⇒  ls -lrt
total 8
drwxrwxr-t  30 alex  staff  1088 Aug  4 14:34 USB
drwx------   1 root  wheel   568 Aug  4 23:59 Family Backup
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel   340 Aug  5 00:00 Time Machine Backups
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     1 Nov 14 20:55 System -> /
drwxr-xr-x  39 root  wheel  1394 Nov 14 20:57 SmileyBackup
```

In addition there you can see that my main drive is **System**. OS X creates a link to / for it automatically.

Also, **Smiley Backup** is another disk, and **Time Machine Backups** is a TimeMachine volume, and **Family Backup** is a remote shared drive I've mounted from another system.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can view almost all mounted devices in `/Volumes`.  Although, the newer iOS devices do not show up there.

Alternatively, you can use `diskutil` (which does not require superuser access.)

```
$ diskutil list
```

If you want more details on a specific mounted device you might try:

```
$ diskutil info [diskname]
```